# How do you get a website to be seen by others

Tags: web, server

I'm new to node.js and I have some questions about how servers work. It may be a bit silly but my understanding of a server is that it is what we use to share our website with others. Consider the following code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

When we run the following code we say that we have "created a server". And when we go to "***http://127.0.0.1:8081/***" we get the desired result. However, what I don't get is that if we have "created a server" why is it that only the computer that  executed the node.js file can access the web address? I know that http://127.0.0.1:8081/ isn't unique and one has to buy a domain name. or use some form of free hosting. However, I don't see how all these thing are tied together.

When creating html files we are able to view them in the browser but no one else can because we didn't have a server set up. What I thought is that once I learned about severs I would finally be able to host a website. I think what I'm wanting here is an explanation of how one goes from **HTML**, **css** **javascript** etc to having a website up and running.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is a special IP address that only exists on the "loopback" network interface (`lo`). To host a site so others can see it, you need to bind your server to an IP address that is available from one of your other network interfaces (such as `eth0`). Each of your interfaces is assigned 1 IP address. You can bind to any of them, or you can bind to `0.0.0.0`, which means it'll be available on any network interface, at the IP address used by the particular interface (e.g. 127.0.0.1 on `lo`, or your `eth`123.100.123.100` on `eth0`, etc.)

Comment: The keyword for this task is "**web hosting**". So, for example, hit your search engine with "web hosting at home". Note: Hosting a website on your home PC takes a bit of time to set up, and comes with risks.

Comment: @Alexander your comment was to complicated for me to understand. I'm pretty new to node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Crash Course: What is a Server?

> I'm new to node.js and I have some questions about how servers work. It may be a bit silly but my understanding of a server is that it is what we use to share our website with others.

The term **server** is quite generic. Simply, a **server** is a program or a machine that serves data or functionality (services) to **clients**; a **client** is a program or machine that receives data or services from a **server**.

### Examples of Servers and Clients

Important: The concept of servers and clients is not unique to node.js or websites. Here are some other types of servers:

- A **Home Media Server** serves photos, music, and videos. Clients include media player apps inside computers/phones/tablets in your home.
- A **Mail Server** serves emails. Clients include email apps inside computers/phones/tablets all over the Internet.
- A **Web Server** serves HTML, CSS, Javascript files, as well as online content like photos, videos, PDF documents, etc. Clients include web browsers.

A server and a client can be very "close" together (such as being inside the same *program* on the same computer), or they can be ver "far" apart (such as being inside different computers in different countries, separated by the Internet). Or, they could be somewhere in between (such as being inside different computers in the same house).

## Crash Course: What is 127.0.0.1?

> if we have "created a server" why is it that only the computer that executed the node.js file can access the web address?

127.0.0.1 is a special **IP address** that is also called **localhost**. Simply, it refers to *"the machine that hosts this application"*. When you tell your web browser to visit 127.0.0.1, your web browser looks for a server on the same computer that it's running on.

If you use your phone's web browser to visit 127.0.0.1, it won't look for a server on your computer that's running node.js. Instead, it will look for a server on your phone.

## How to View Website on Another Machine in Your Home?

You need to do several steps if you want to let your phone view the website on your computer. I will give you a summary, but you must research the topics in-depth yourself:

1. Your phone and node.js PC must be on the **same subnet**. You can probably achieve this by connecting both devices to the same Wi-Fi network.
2. You must find out your PC's **local IP address**. You can use `ipconfig` if your PC runs Windows, or use `ifconfig` if it runs Linux.
3. You must tell your PC's **firewall** to allow incoming traffic on the **TCP port** used by your web server. In your example, you are using port `8081`.
4. Finally, tell your phone's web browser your PC's **local IP address** and **port**. For example, if your PC's IP address is 192.168.1.20, then use your phone to visit http://192.168.1.20:8081/

## How to View Website on Another Machine over the Internet?

This is a topic for another day.

> What I thought is that once I learned about severs I would finally be able to host a website.

Sorry, that is not enough. There is a lot more involved. Start by researching the topics I've already mentioned, in bold.